# What are good estimates for phonemes length?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-processing, speech, voice

I am working in a phoneme recognition project, the language that I am using is "English". I have a tool that converts each written phrase in phonemes. Also I have an estimation of the time length of each word. I would like to know also the duration of every single phoneme. Does any one know if there is a good source where I can resort to know the duration of the phonemes in the English language?

Answer (score 1):

NLTK has an interface/downloader for a sample of the TIMIT phoneme corpus (http://nltk.sourceforge.net/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.timit-module.html), and it should be straightforward to get the lengths of the phoneme recordings in that corpus.

Comment: The source code of the  of the stage that I need  isn't available   (phonetic())    :(